# Issue with Apache redirection

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I want to redirect `mysite.example` or `http://mysite.example` or `www.mysite.example` or any other format given my user to `http://www.mysite.example`, I am able to achieve this by rewriting following lines in my `.htaccess` file

```
Rewritecond %{http_host} ^mysite.example
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mysite.example/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I want do this from Apache, so I've added following line in `Virtual host conf file of the site` and removed above two lines from `.htaccess`

```
Redirect 301 / http://mysite.example/
```

But whenever I'm trying to access the site following error is displyaing,

```
Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.
```

Where am I wrong

Comment: isn't this a predestined question for serverfault?

Comment: i flagged, but to be of help, the 310 error indicates that you have a redirection loop going on. i also suspect that the "Redirect 301" is wrong, seems to me you are redirecting from the root directory to mysite.com (which is also the root directory)... hence you get an infinite loop.

Comment: @DKOATED: Thanks, after removing the `/` then its working as expected.

Comment: @DKOATED: it won't create other issues, because I'm going to change this on `Liver Server`

Comment: You should find a suitable redirect solution in one of ten I found when searching. Additionally there is even a tag for situations like this called [tag:no-www]

Comment: *I want to redirect mysite.example or http://mysite.example*. this is technically exactly the same thing. Precisely the first is an hostname, while the latter is an URL that is a scheme (HTTP) plus an hostname. When you enter just an hostname in any tool, browser or CLI, right now HTTP is by default. This is also the same as `http://mysite.example/` because the path is mandatory in HTTP dialog so if you put nothing like in first URL, the tool will just use the default of `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R]
```

which was copied directly from [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html). You really ought to read through that page and understand it.

Your current rewrite rule, as it stands, sends every request to a local server path that your apache config probably cannot deliver ('/' is the root directory of your server not the root of your website). Apache in turn will try to respond to that with an error page, which in turn gets redirected to the '/' again, hence an infinite redirect.

The above code only redirects requests NOT bound for www.example.com and preserves the rest of the URL when it redirects.

Answer (score 0):

**Your directive causes an infinite redirection loop.**

The reason is that a 301 gets returned to the browser and that host and path are really separate things, despite forming a URL. When a browser sees a 301 redirect to `http://site.example/` it interprets it as find `site.example` and ask for the `/` path from the standard HTTP port.

With your unconditional rule, which is valid for `site.example`, the 301 is returned again which sends them in an infinite loop.